# Unable to set new owner on Windows Defender. Access is denied

Tags: windows, windows-defender, regedit

I was trying to disable Windows Defender realtime scanning due to the inordinate amount of resources it uses. Yes, I am aware of the consequences.

I have tired disabling the service in GPEDIT but can't make any changes.

But I still can't change the key, or it's owner.

```
Unable to set new owner on Windows Defender. Access is denied.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to take ownership of Windows Defender.
To disable Windows Defender real-time scanning do this:

- Run *Settings > Update & Security > Windows Security*
- Click Open Windows Security
- Click Manage settings
- Click Real-time protection to turn it Off.

The effect is immediate.